# Microsoft power BI embed with our application

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I have a few questions about Microsoft power BI.

I have a dotnet core 2.0 web application. Now I want to build a report system for my clients. So i am looking for a good service to help me to build the report system. I Found Power BI. But I do not know if it could achieve my goal or not. So basically I need some head start information from anyone who has used this to the same task That i am going to describe.

1. Does it fully compatible with dot.net core 2.0 web application?
2. If I want to build a front-end page to let my clients to customize their own report template e.g. moving content, writing text, ajust font-size, can I do it with power BI?or anthing like iFrame can export the 'template builder' from power BI to my application

Thanks

Comment: See if this is for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/.

Comment: For requirement 2, it seems like you should just publish a data source and have end users use that their own Power BI

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid but I would like to keep them inside my application to do the customisation. Is it doable? Btw, how is Microsoft BI work with AWS? Thanks